# grouping of xml elements based on one attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a scenario like this in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<container>
  <param name="paramA" value="valueA" />
  <param name="paramB" value="valueB" />
  ...
</container>
```

and  i want to obtain the results as...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<container>
   <paramA>
  <param value="valueA" />
   </paramA>

   <paramB>
  <param  value="valueB" />
   </paramB>

</container>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no *grouping* here that I can see. -- Note also that your output format is awkward; it will be more difficult to process than the input.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <container>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="container/*"/>
        </container>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="param">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@value"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```